# Dataframe structures in pandas/seaborn. Do I need to be careful about observations vs variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm learning how to use python for data analysis and I have my first few dataframes to work with that I have pulled from video games I play.

So the dataframe I'm working with currently uses the header row for all the player names (8 players)
All the statistics are the first column.

Is it a better practice to have these positions reversed. i.e. should all the players be in the first col instead of the first row?

```
Arctic  Shat    Sly Snky    Nanm    Zax zack    Sorn    Cort
Statistics                                  
Assists 470 415 388 182 212 92  40  5   4
Avg Damage Dealt    203.82  167.37  165.2   163.45  136.3   85.08   114.96  128.72  26.71
Boosts  1972    1807    1790    668 1392    471 103 7   33
Damage Dealt    236222.66   239680.08   164373.73   74696.195   99904.48    27991.652   13910.629   901.01385   1228.7041
Days    206 234 218 78  157 94  29  3   10
Head Shot Kills 395 307 219 119 130 29  12  0   0
Headshot %  26.37%  18.65%  18.96%  23.85%  19.58%  16.11%  17.14%  0%  0%
Heals   3139    4385    2516    1326    2007    749 382 15  78
K/D 1.36    1.2 1.22    1.13    0.95    0.58    0.59    0.57    0.07
Kills   1498    1646    1155    499 664 180 70  4   3
Longest Kill    461.77765   430.9177    410.534 292.18732   354.3065    287.72366   217.98175   110.25433   24.15225
Longest Time Survived   2051.842    2180.98 1984.259    1948.513    2064.065    1979.101    2051.846    1486.288    1670.048
Losses  1117    1376    959 448 709 320 119 7   46
Max Kill Streaks    4   4   4   3   4   3   3   1   1
Most Survival Time  2051.842    2180.98 1984.259    1948.513    2064.065    1979.101    2051.846    1486.288    1670.048
Revives 281 455 155 104 221 83  19  2   2
Ride Distance   1610093.4   2157408.8   1572710 486170.5    714986.3    524297  204585.53   156.07877   63669.613
Road Kills  1   4   5   4   0   0   0   0   0
Round Most Kills    9   8   9   7   9   6   5   2   1
Rounds Played   1159    1432    995 457 733 329 121 7   46
Suicides    16  42  14  6   10  4   4   0   2
Swim Distance   2830.028    4966.6914   2703.0044   1740.3292   2317.7866   1035.3792   395.86472   0   92.01848
Team Kills  22  47  23  9   15  4   5   0   2
Time Survived   969792.2    1284232.6   930141.94   328190.22   637273.3    284434.3    109724.04   4580.869    37748.414
Top10s  531 654 509 196 350 187 74  2   28
Vehicle Destroys    23  9   29  4   15  3   1   0   0
Walk Distance   1545281.6   1975185 1517812 505191  1039509.8   461860.53   170913.25   9665.322    63900.125
Weapons Acquired    5043    7226    4683    1551    2909    1514    433 23  204
Wins    55  63  48  17  32  19  3   0   3
dBNOs   1489    1575    1058    488 587 179 78  5   8
```

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe to make your explanations a little clearer

Comment: @yatu I added a screenshot link to my original post with sample.

Comment: Depending on what your going to do with the data, this could be perfectly fine or horrible, more information is needed

Comment: The data is for gathering performance insights, Im just using a small set of data for practice. You can imagine more data with a real esports team @ksooklall What else do you need to know? for example i'm trying to have the x-axis plot out all the players. I want to then assign statistics to the y axis

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: @wwii I'm not sure how to do that with a dataframe, its a virtual excel file. I could export it to .xls and paste that here somehow? This seemed to be the easiest way to get my answer, as the structure of the table index is the important thing here not the code I used to create it

Comment: `df.head(10)` or `print(df.head(10).to_str()` In a shell ; then copy and paste as text.

Comment: @wwii I added that data to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is better to transpose.
The current best practice is to have one instance (row) for each observation, in your case, player. And one feature (column) for each variable.
This is called "tidy data" (from the paper published by Hadley Wickham). Tidy data works more or less like guidelines for us, data scientists, much like normalization rules for relational database people.
Also Most frameworks/programs/data structures are implemented considering this organization. For instance, in python pandas, using a dataframe with this data you have, if you would want to check out the average headshots, would need to check just a `df['Head Shot Kills'].mean()` (if it was transposed...).

Comment: Thanks, 'tidy data' was the keyword I was missing when trying to answer this question. my first instinct is the dataframe.melt to fix my problem @edinho

Comment: I found a copy of the paper @ https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf Thanks again, great answer

Comment: Thanks. If you think it is useful for other people too, mark it as accepted. So others can benefit as well : )